# Attempting to use the QuantumMachineLearning Repositry with vscode and now import qsharp is reporting 'Fail'

Tags: programming, q#

I have been trying to follow the Quantum machine learning kata by using vscode and jupyter notebook, I was using the wrong version of iqsharp so changed it in the code like so:

[image]

As can be seen the attempt to import the machine learning package returns an error and also attempting to use it does not work.
I then went back to try and use the code on vscode but now even attempting to import qsharp is giving this error (it worked before attempting to change the jupyter code):
[image]

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling iqsharp and the QDK, but that doesn't work. Does anyone know what I might have done to break it and how to fix it?

Comment: When you call `import qsharp`, it actually tries to compile all of the .qs files in that folder. So the errors you see are occurring when compiling the .qs files. The errors are indicating that you haven't added the Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning package, which your .qs code must depend on. You will definitely want the `qsharp.packages.add()` and `qsharp.reload()` calls, as you show in your first screenshot.

Comment: Thank you very much! I moved the file but the error still comes up on that file and in the jupyter notebook, would you know anything about that?

Comment: Does [this sample project](https://github.com/microsoft/Quantum/tree/master/samples/machine-learning/wine) help to illustrate the usage of Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning from Python? Look at host.py, which imports and calls operations defined in Training.qs. In particular, I don't think you can call `import Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning` directly from Python as you're trying to do. You can import operations that are defined in your .qs file. Then inside the .qs file you can open the `Microsoft.Quantum.MachineLearning` namespace and call its operations.